# Volume Control in a mostly Silent iOS app

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I've asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828751/best-practice-for-volume-control-ios) before but I feel I should start a new thread since my other thread is dated and probably poorly worded. I'm wondering what the best approach would be for adding volume control to an iOS app the is mostly silent. A good example would be a navigation app that only plays audio when you approach or miss a turn. In such an app, hearing a turn prompt which is not loud enough, the user would want the volume for the prompts to be audible and would naturally used the side volume controls to adjust prompts to their liking.

There are several problems here. One is that audio is not currently playing so the user has no reference as to how much it has been increased. This is more or less expected however there are technical issues that I am more interested in. To link the side volume control to your app you have to start and manage an audio session. I have not found an authoritative reference for such a situation as most documentation assumes you are currently playing or in the process of starting audio. Managing an audio session for a mostly silent app seems to be an edge case, though I find it rather common in that two of the major apps I've worked on require such functionality.

Of the various problems associated with audio session management, you have to address killing and restoring the audio session as you move in and out of the background. You have to consider other apps playing audio as you begin and stop the session. Depending on your type of app, you may have other more advanced needs such as custom override routing to the speakers, custom mute controls, etc. If you have any experience with such an app could you elaborate on how you addressed such challenges and expound on other issues?

Comment: Have you looked at the iOS documentation? This behavior is well defined in the human interaction guidelines and they even include implementation examples as well.

Comment: Your question seems a little too broad for this Q&A format, even though on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

One very common merhod is to set the audio session category appropriate for the type of app at launch, no matter whether sound is immanent or won't be played till tomorrow (as long as the purpose and settings of the app is to play such).

Added:

One way to allow to user to adjust the volume when the app is silent is to provide some means for the user to have your app to immediately start (and/or maybe stop) playing some sound with an amplitude typical for your app: some calibration tone/talk, your copyright notice, trademark jingle, or a safety message, for instance.

Comment: You are confusing the audio session with the audio category. You set the category for the classification of the app, (eg. VOIP, navigation, etc.) Apple recommends that you typically begin a session before you wish to play audio which highlights my overall question of how to allow the user to control volume when there is nothing playing?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I see when developing apps that are mostly silent regard moving in/out of the foreground and playing nicely with other audio. To give a better idea of what I usually do I'll give some snippets from a recent project. (These are intentionally incomplete and only meant to illustrate a point.) For the sake of argument let's assume we have an AudioManager class that is responsible for maintaining the audio sessions. This class is what we use to instantiate our custom audio player. In such a class we put:

```
@interface MyAudioManager ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) BOOL alwaysMaintainAudioSession;
@property (nonatomic, retain) MyCustomAudioPlayer *player;
@end

@implementation MyAudioManager
@synthesize alwaysMaintainAudioSession;
@synthesize player;

-(void) applicationWillEnterForeground
{
    isInBackground = NO;
    if (NO==[self anyAudioIsPlaying] && self.alwaysMaintainAudioSession) {
        [self activateAudioSession];
    }
}

-(void) activateAudioSession
{
    AudioSessionSetActive(TRUE);
    AudioSessionAddPropertyListener ( kAudioSessionProperty_AudioRouteChange, AudioPropertyListener, self);
}

-(BOOL) anyAudioIsPlaying
{
    return [self otherAudioIsPlaying] || [player isPlaying];
}

-(BOOL) otherAudioIsPlaying
{
    UInt32 yesNo;
    UInt32 propertySize = sizeof(yesNo);
    OSStatus status = AudioSessionGetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OtherAudioIsPlaying, &propertySize, &yesNo);
    if (kAudioSessionUnsupportedPropertyError == status) {
        return MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying == [theiPodMusicPlayer playbackState];
    } else {
        return MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying == [theiPodMusicPlayer playbackState] || yesNo;
    }
}
```

The manager allows you to set a property that always keeps the volume control linked to the app sounds which means we always make sure either a session is active or some other app is playing audio. In any other case the volume control reverts to controlling the ringer. So when entering the foreground we have to check for any other audio playing and conditionally activate the audio session. We also need to close the session when moving to the background to restore the ringer volume control.

```
-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground
{
    if (NO==[self anyAudioIsPlaying]) {
        AudioSessionSetActive(NO);
    }
}
```

In my solution I include a bunch of other code to handle things like responding intelligently when bluetooth audio devices are connected, factory methods for creating the custom player, custom audio compression and more. The main idea, however, is handling other apps playing audio while attempting to keep the volume control linked to app volume while in the foreground.